# Defining a type array of strings: A rest element type must be an array type.ts(2574)

Tags: typescript

I have an object with a "required" property whose value will be an array of strings, eg:

```js
{
  required: ["id", "name", "status"]    
}
```

The above strings must always be included in the above array, but there may also be optional, other string items; eg:

```js
{
  required: [
    "id", "name", "status", // always mandatory
    "foo", "bar" // optional extra items
  ]    
}
```

I can create an interface in a `d.ts` file to define this quite neatly:

```js
interface JsonSchemaI {
  required: [
    "id",
    "name",
    "status",
    ...string
  ];
}
```

The `...string` spreads an unlimited amount of optional string values into the array while enforcing the hard-coded string values. But when I try to achieve the same in a plain `.ts` file, I get the error: `A rest element type must be an array type.ts(2574)`

How do I make the same work in a `.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that swapping `...string` for `...string[]` fixed it. I don't understand why `d.ts` files read this differently from `.ts` files though?